# Apple iOS: give access to paid app version from free app without any charge

Tags: ios, app-store, promotions, promotion-code, in-app-promotions

I have two apps:

- A paid app that costs $0.99 (without ads)
- A free app - without ads

In free version I have share page and if user shares the app 10 times they should be able to get pro (paid) version for free.

I can't figure out how to make this. How to give access some users to download paid app for free in some cases.

I searched for promo codes but it seems that it is hard coded values and it is limited to 100 codes in total. Is there a way to make things dynamically?

Comment: You need to read about shared keychain,  http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/

Comment: Don't think got anyway, you should just remove ads by code in your free app

Comment: @AnandSuthar thank you for instant reply, but it does not help

Comment: This is not a supported model in the app store.  You could unlock the pro features in the free app after the 10 shares.  In fact it sounds like you should only have one app with an in-app purchase to provide the pro features.  Then if they share 10 times you unlock without the in-app purchase